# ESP8266 as a internet interface (access point)

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, iot, esp8266

I made some experiments with this amazing module. Now I'm trying to level up my project so I connected it to my Raspberry Pi via UART.

I'm able to send AT commands to make simple connections like I do on my Arduino. How can Linux "see" it like a real WLAN0 interface?

I'd like to use the ESP8266 as an access point to surf the web (maybe bridging the ethernet cable interface).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't (easily) make the ESP8266 a true WiFi device for Linux. Although projects like [this one here](http://hackaday.com/2015/12/09/raspberry-pi-wifi-through-sdio/) have figured out how to put the device into an ESP8089 mode to use it as a true WLAN interface, it requires modifying the module itself.

You can, however, use the device's AT API to connect to the internet through a UART and send any arbitrary data, or develop your own firmware to pass data back and forth to a server with the ESP8266 - None of these though would allow a seamless TCP connection like an actual WiFi card would, however.